# Using a Query Calculation From a Parameter and If Statement as a Crosstab Intersection ERROR

Tags: parameters, crosstab, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm using IBM Cognos Report Studio Version 10.2.2

I'm trying to create a crosstab but am receiving the following error message:
"An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='-237'." with the following detail "CAF-WRN-2082 An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator. The complete error has been logged by CAF with SecureErrorID:2018-03-21-06:30:41.717-#3"

The crosstab node members are Location (horizontal) & Department (vertical) from the Source (there are a total of 13 locations & 11 departments, but only 4 departments are being filtered).

I created a prompt so a number between 0-147 needs to be entered for each Location and created a data item [# of Residents] linked to the parameter (a data item per location's parameter i.e. [ILA # of Residents] is 29).

I created a data item [Proj - PRD] where the expression is an IF statement:

```
IF([Proj - Department]='DIN') THEN (0.8) ELSE (IF([Proj - Department]='HCAL')    
THEN (1.8) ELSE (IF([Proj - Department]='HCMC') THEN (2.5) ELSE (IF([Proj - 
Department]='HSK') THEN (0.3) ELSE ('ERROR'))))
```

I created another data item to cast [Proj - PRD] as numeric (I was previously receiving an error message where something was populating as a varchar):

```
cast([Proj - PRD],numeric)
```

Last but not least, I created another data item [PRD Calculation] to multiply the # of Residents & PRD, wanting to use it as the crosstab intersection:

```
[Proj - PRD Casted]*[ILA # of Residents]
```

I'm not receiving an errors when I'm validating the report & am prompted to enter a number when I run the report, but receive the above error message after entering 29 for ILA (I've only set up the prompt with a single location at the moment until I can get the report to run correctly)

Also, as a sidetone, the reason I'm trying to create this crosstab is to compare it to another crosstab that shows total actual hours worked by location & department from the Source (the [PRD Calculation] is the projected total hours worked by location & department).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your IF statement. The ELSE is outputting a string some of the time ('ERROR'). This is incompatible with the other values you are outputting, which are all floating point numbers. Additionally, you are trying to cast the value to numeric which will fail when 'ERROR' is outputted. Lastly, you are multiplying the value with another number, which again will not work with a string.

One possible solution is to output -1 instead of 'ERROR'. This is a number and compatible with the other values you are outputting. You can modify logic later to interpret a -1 value as 'ERROR' for display or other purposes.